# Javascript Array Object Property Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, arrayobject

When I attempt to access the array object (`preivous_data`) the console outputs this:

```
[Object { label="line1", data=[13]}]
```

as expected. However, when I access the array object property (`preivous_data.data`) the console gives `undefined`. I am confused - what error am I making for this not to display the array values for the property `data` in the object?

As a further test, I converted the object with `JSON.stringify`, then back into a JavaScript object. Again I found the same issues with accessing the property value of the object:

```
function dataUpdate(passed_onDataReceived_data){

      console.log("passed object")                     // console output:  passed object

      preivous_data = passed_onDataReceived_data
      console.log(preivous_data)                       // console output: [Object { label="line1", data=[13]}]
      console.log(preivous_data.data)                  // console output: undefined

      var JSON_Stringify = JSON.stringify(preivous_data);
      console.log(JSON_Stringify)                     // console output:[{"label":"line1","data":[[0,88],[1,28],[2,52],[3,7],[4,93],[5,78],[6,53],[7,64],[8,43],[9,77],[10,58],[11,74],[12,5]]}]
      var myObject = eval('(' + JSON_Stringify + ')')
      console.log(myObject)                           // console output: [Object { label="line1", data=[13]}]
      console.log(myObject.data)                      // console output: undefined
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have the object `previous_data` as an array.

```
[Object { label="line1", data=[13]}]
```

So you need to do `previous_data[0].data` to access the data attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To solve the answers while waiting for help I decided to grab copy the data attribute to a new var, then manipulate it and then update the passed_onDataReceived_data.